# Put a QToolBar in a QWidget instead of QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qmainwindow, qtoolbar

I am trying to put a QToolBar on a layout of a QWidget instead of QMainWindow. On QMainWindow and QWidget is working fine, but when i try to add it on a layout first, is not. Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible? Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys


img = '../../Images/logo.png'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


    mainWin = QtGui.QMainWindow()    

    widget = QtGui.QWidget()    
    hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    '''ToolBar On main Window '''    

    basicToolBar = mainWin.addToolBar('Basic')
    basicToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QAction('Test', mainWin))
#    basicToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(img), 'Test', mainWin))

#    mainWin.show()


    '''ToolBar On Widget '''

    # Case 1: Set widget as parent
#    widgetToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(widget)
#    widgetToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QAction('Test', widget))
#    widgetToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(img), QtGui.QAction('Test', widget))

    # Case 2: Set toolBat on a layout
    widgetToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar()
    widgetToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QAction('Test', None))
#   widgetToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(img), 'Test', None))    
    hLayout.addWidget(widgetToolBar)  
    widget.setLayout(hLayout)

    widget.show()

    # Run 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does it mean that I do not work?

Comment: Put on a layout is not working (Case 2)

Comment: I'm curious why you do not want to use QMainWindow ?, I just checked the source code of QMainWindow and it has a custom layout.

Comment: Because this is going to be on a QTabWidget, and the QTabWidget within a QMainWindow. At least this is what I am trying to make.

Comment: you could put a picture of what you want to get, I think you could use a second QMainWindow but it will not be clear until you fully understand what you want. On the other hand you have a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), 
I find it difficult to implement a QToolBar in a QWidget

Comment: So, you think that the best solution would be to put a secondary QMainWindow ?

Comment: yes, but if you want a solution I would have to understand how you want the widget to be displayed.

Comment: QMainWindow with a QTabWidget as a central widget. Each tab has a QWidget. Each QWidget will have a different toolbar and their own QTabWidget too. For now, i only want to put a toolbar within each tab.

Comment: Do you want the following? https://imgur.com/a/IrhezmI

Comment: Yes, and below the toolBar another QTabWidget. Now you have the full picture

Comment: Is this what you want or something else? https://imgur.com/a/OwBveLO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177739/discussion-between-ioaniatr-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QToolBar can only be in a QMainWindow since the QMainWindow has a special layout.

So you can use a secondary QMainWindow without problems as I show below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tabwidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabwidget)
        for name in ("tab1", "tab2", "tab3"):
            self.create_widgets(name)

    def create_widgets(self, name):
        w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.tabwidget.addTab(w, name)
        basicToolBar = w.addToolBar('Basic')
        basicToolBar.addAction('Test')
        basicToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon("home.png"), 'Test')
        tab = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        w.setCentralWidget(tab)
        for i in range(10):
            tab.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), "tab-{}".format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I Just tested your example, seems that is working fine. But, you say that I can NOT also use a secondary QMainWindow without problems ? What problems do you think that I would have?

Comment: @ioaniatr No, no problem, I'm a little tired and I wrote it wrong, :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm have you read the description of QToolBar? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#details 
I think it won't work like this if your Object isn't a child of QMainWindow. The documentation says:

> When a QToolBar is not a child of a QMainWindow, it loses the ability to populate the extension pop up with widgets added to the toolbar using addWidget(). Please use widget actions created by inheriting QWidgetAction and implementing QWidgetAction::createWidget() instead.

Comment: I haven't try to put some actions on it yet. I am trying only to make it show. Am I going to lose the ability to put actions there like 'select file from folder' ?

Comment: seems like. Do I get you right? You just want to show a toolbar on a widget in your application, not on the (Main)Window of your application...???

Comment: Yes, but if it is not possible, i am thinking to replace the widget with a secondary QMainWindow. Not sure what would be the best.